# Javascript regex help, negative lookahead

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm battling through some pieces of regex today and while I've bashed a couple of them off with the help of some old threads from here, I'm a bit stuck on this last one.

```
Data sample
SOMETEXT
OTHERWORDS
po8 34t
NAME. VALUE
SURNAME. VALUE
```

Behind the NAME is a postcode that I want to try and extract. Obviously a postcode can be either 6 or 7 digits (+1 whitespace). So the approaches I've though of a negative lookahead for the postcode so I tried this, hoping to use the newline as a stop point (basically read everythign on the line above NAME until the previous line:

```
/NAM(?!([/s/S]))/
```

But that doesn't really seem to be a workable solution. I've played around with other snippets in the square brackets but this is pretty much where I am right now. Then I thought about substrings but I can't find any good regex resources specific to javascript. Any ideas?

Maybe there's a better way to do this via regex which I'm also open to?

```
TEST DATA ADDED ON REQUEST
ORGANISATION CODE
ORGANISATION NAME
ORGANSIATION DEPT
Tel:  0000 777 6666 ROAD
Fax: 0000 777 6666 PLACE
REGION
ZIP
NAME
CODE
ADDRESS1,
ADDRESS NAME,
ADDRESS PLACE,
REGION1
AA6 1ZZ (POSTCODE)
NAME: SURNAME, FORENAME
SPELL NO. 1111111
PERSON ID. 1111111A
SPOUSE ID. 2222222B
Date: 11 Month Year
LETTER CONTENTS (WILL VARY)
```

So the value I am after is **before** (Postcode), preceding NAME but REGION1 can be very different

Comment: What you posted as a sample input does does not seem to include `NAME` followed with 6 or 7 digits. It would be `/\bNAME\s*(\d{6,7})/` then, or `/\bNAME\.?\s*(\d{6,7})/`

Comment: add a data-set for test please (with random fake value that look alike valid one)

Comment: do you have `(POSTCODE)` in your data-set or its' to show the part ?

Comment: I suggest [`/^([a-zA-Z0-9]{3} [a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4})\r?\nNAME:/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/fX1vE0/1).

Comment: update of my post : `/(.+)(?:\n|\r)+NAME:` will do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE** :

[`/(?:\n|\r)+(.{6,7})(?:\n|\r)+NAME:/`](https://regex101.com/r/nJ4xB2/4) is maybe more strict to get what you want

---

[`/(.+)(?:\n|\r)+NAME:/`](https://regex101.com/r/nJ4xB2/3) is a simple one that just take what the line before `NAME:`

Comment: And if there is `DEPARTMENT\nNAME:`? You will get `DEPARTMENT` as a result. You can replace `(?:\n|\r)+` with `[\r\n]+`, a character class is more efficient than alternation group since you are using single characters as alternatives.

Comment: he don't give us real data for test and is `6 or 7 digits` are with letter in the data-test :/ So I just provide the simplest thing; but yes, if you got `NAME:`  somewhere I'll bring back the previous line

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew update, this one will avoid `DEPARTMENT`

Comment: Thanks, I went with the stricter expression and it is working great. I will mark this as answer when i can. Couldn't get the first example working on regex101.com

Answer (score 1):

If I am understood your question, maybe this helps you:

```
NAME\.([\s]?)(\d{6,7})
```

If you want to use it in JS, use `g` modifier for the groups.

Comment: This might fetch more results than is necessary.